# .htaccess how to block specific url

Tags: .htaccess, url, block, spam-prevention

I suffered an attack on the site. a spammer has created a proxy that begins with a page 487032.asp on different domains
can I stop into .htaccess all requests from url containing the string 487032.asp? How?

e.g. deny from *487032.asp

thank's

Mario

Answer (score 2):

Create this rewrite rule in your .htaccess for blocking this bad URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /487032\.asp [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<FilesMatch ".*487032\.asp$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: note that this only works with actual files, not with arbitrary urls